# Enable general logging mysql 5.6.14

Tags: mysql

I have mysq 5.6.14 and centos 6.4. In /etc/my.cnf I have:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
bind-address=127.0.0.1
character-set-server=utf8
init-connect="SET NAMES utf8"
skip-character-set-client-handshake
general_log=1
general_log_file=/var/log/mysql
log-output=file
```

When I make a mistake in my.cnf I cant restart mysql (service mysql restart). It means that mysql reads this file. However I don't have /var/log/mysql file. What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. This may seem like a clugy band-aid, but try the following for now...

```
service mysql stop
touch /var/log/mysql.log
chown mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql.log
service mysql start
```

This should work.

Please look back at the database home folder (run SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';)

Go to the folder and see if a default general log appeared.

You could also try changing it to

```
general_log = 1
general_log_file = mysql.log
```

and see if the mysql.log appears in your datadir folder after restarting mysql